# how to create boolean method to check that an object added to arraylist with specific index in java

Tags: java, arraylist

1. How to add a new Object to `ArrayList` into specific index?
   o = Object; index = New Object index; 
   return true if success, false if not.

---

```
import java.util.Collection;

public class RaArrayList implements RaCollection {

    public static ArrayList<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public boolean add(int index, Object o) {

        for (index = 0; index < obj.size(); index ++) {
            o = obj.get(index);
            o = new Object();

            if (obj.add(index, o)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**My `main()`**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Islam s = new Islam();
    System.out.println(s.add(1, "Islam"));  
}
```

Comment: You are not using the `index` passed to your method. Instead you are trying all indices from 0 (inclusive) to the size of you list (exclusive).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. “Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.” If your program doesn’t behave as desired, please tell us precisely in which way not. Then you will get better help sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

- You are probably already aware that this line cannot be compiled: `if (obj.add(index, o)) {`. In my Eclipse I get “Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to boolean”. This is because, even though the one-arg `add()` returns a boolean (always true, though), the two-arg `add()`, which you are using, is declared void and therefore cannot return anything. Therefore you can not use it as a condition in your `if` statement. So how can you know whether the insertion was successful? Simple: from the fact that no exception is thrown (the method throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if you provide an invalid index). So just call the method and then unconditionally return `true` from your own method. To return false on failure, surround the call to `obj.add()` with `try`-`catch` and return false in the `catch` part.
- The call `obj.get(index)` too may throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Fortunately you don’t need it, just delete that line.
- You are not using the two arguments passed to your method, `index` and `o`.  Instead you are trying all indices from 0 (inclusive) to the size of you list (exclusive). For every such index, you are creating a new object rather than using the one provided to you, like I assume you had intended. Solution: drop the for loop and drop the two statements assigning to `o`.
- Since the list is empty from the start, your `for` loop runs 0 times, that is, not at all. Therefore your method immediately goes to the last line and returns `false` without having added anything to your `ArrayList`. Once you drop the loop and the `if` statement, the `return false;` will be unreachable and should be deleted too.
- The class you have declared is called `RaArrayList`, but in your `main` method you are instead instantiating a class called `Islam`. I suppose it should have been the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:
        o = obj.get(index);
        o = new Object();
You assign obj to your "o". And then you assign empty obj to "o".